# SQL select startwith (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I need to find a list of all items starting with an underscore: _

The obvious doesn't work:

```
select * from role where Name like '_%'
```

This still returns all items.

The following also returns all items.

```
select * from role where Name like '\_%'
select * from role where Name like '__%'
```

anyone knows how to escape a underscore? or how else I can achieve this StartWithUnderscore functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

select * from role where Name like '[_]%';

Answer (score 0):

You can escape with any character you want eg

```
select * from role where Name like '!_%' ESCAPE'!'
```

You can read more on this page: [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)